# Improper symbols getting rendered in the comment

Tags: bug, status-deferred

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205063/how-to-make-each-page-element-non-printable-by-default-in-bootstrap/28205124?noredirect=1#comment44776184_28205124) question contains a bug, one of the comments contains strange symbol which wasn't entered by me

```
... :not(.visible-print-inline‌​-block) ...
```

While

```
... :not(.visible-print-inline-block) ...
```

should be rendered

Google Chrome 40.0.2214.93, Mac OS X 10.10.1 - problem exists

Safari 8.0.2 (10600.2.5) - problem does not exists

FireFox 35.0.1 - problem does not exists

[image]

Comment: Might help to add a screenshot for those of us on browsers that don't exhibit the problem.

Comment: Note those two lines look exactly the same to me in Google Chrome 40.0.2214.93 m (64-bit), Windows 8.1.

Comment: I've updated the question with an image as requested

Comment: I've just noticed that when you open an image in new window and scale it, there's also some strange yellow stripe behind this symbol, really strange...

Comment: This is intentional - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91512. Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970. For what it's worth, I can reproduce this on OS X 10.9, Chrome 40.0.2213.93 and 40.0.2213.94, 64-bit.

Comment: To show what Jeremiah is talking about, copy and pasting the code block in the question in my console: `':not(.visible-print-inline‌​-block)'.length ==>
35` (first)
`':not(.visible-print-inline-block)'.length ==>
33` (second)

Comment: What’s the deal with [meta-tag:status-norepro]? [I ran repro the bug, for what it’s worth.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285431/1968)

Comment: @Geoff: I can reproduce it just fine, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449209 It probably is Mac OS X only, however.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose that deserves a mention at the chromium forums.  There's not much we can do about it.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: I saw it a few days ago, but didn't bother to report it here when I found the Chromium bug report. I should've known people would report it against Stack Exchange anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a confirmed Chrome bug, see [issue 449209](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449209). It appears to be limited to Mac OS X only (the developer confirming the issue could not reproduce it on Ubuntu and Windows).

In any case, this is not anything that Stack Exchange can fix, this is up to the Chrome developers.

Comment: “this is not anything that Stack Exchange can fix” – Well, that’s just not true. Stack Overflow users are experiencing this problem for the sole reason that SO started including code to work around *other browsers’* rendering issues. Since the “fix” obviously isn’t one, it could easily be reverted. Note: I’m actually *not* suggesting this, it’s a bug that I can easily live with.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: the fix in question worked fine since 2011, that Chrome broke `&zwnj;` display is clearly a Chrome issue that'll be fixed soon enough.

Comment: @Marijn Sure, but SO has worked around browser bugs before, and in fact the current bug is a consequence of that.