# Weird character in comments after link

Tags: bug, comments, design

I’ve noticed this a few times before, but now it happened in one of my own comments and I could verify that it’s inserted by the website, not me:

[image: Screenshot]

The screenshot was made in Chrome 40.0.2214.94 on OS X 10.9.5.

Inspecting the comment source code, I see that the website has inserted two characters:

```
<span class="comment-copy">Depending on the compiler,
<a href="http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/02/07/cpp-convert-int-to-string-speed/" rel="nofollow">Boost.Spirit.Karma handily beats
<code>sprintf</code></a>&zwnj;&#8203;.
There’s also the FastFormat library, but I’ve never used that.</span>
```

So we have here zero-width non-joiner (200C) and a zero-width space (U+200B), and the browser displays them as boxes.

And I’ve inspected the *comment itself* using a hex editor:

[image: xxd output]

– Clearly, the characters are not present there.

Comment: Did you edit this out of your comment? Do you have a live example of a comment where this still exists?

Comment: @Shog9 I didn’t edit it out – I *can’t*, it’s not in the comment text I entered, look at the hex dump. The screenshot is a link to the original comment.

Comment: @Will Explanation yes, but I wouldn’t say dupe, since I’m actually reporting a (previously unreported) bug here. It’s a dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284817/1968, but the [meta-tag:status-norepro] bugs me …

Comment: It has been around a long time, and tested before, isn't this just a Chrome regression?

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it's a _Chrome_ issue, as running Chrome 40.0.2214.94 on Windows 7 is not showing me the same issue that's being reported. I think Chrome has something to do with it, but not everything or more users would probably be seeing this.

Comment: @Kendra: I do see the issue on Chrome on Mac. I did confirm that it is the reported Chrome issue.

Comment: First reported 4 months ago, fixed 22 hours ago.  Nice timing :)